# Appendix name in Uppercase but in Appendix TOC lowercased

Tags: table-of-contents, appendix

I'm writing a thesis in which there is an appendix. It's referenced in the TOC of appendixes. However, there is a requirement as to :

- have the appendix name in Uppercase where the appendix actually is
- and in the Appendix TOC, it should appear in lowercase

I declare the appendix with :

```
\Annexe{Échantillons Utilisés}
```

Which makes it ok for the lowercase req. in TOC, but doesn't make it appear in Uppercase at the appendix title.

[Here](https://share.polymtl.ca/alfresco/service/api/path/content;cm:content/workspace/SpacesStore/Company%20Home/Sites/bibliopoly/documentLibrary/libguides_francais/Gabarit_bilingue.zip?a=true&guest=true) is the template to use.
Additionally, here is [the main page](https://libguides.biblio.polymtl.ca/c.php?g=480359&p=3284762) on which you can retrieve the template in case of a broken link.

I was thinking of looking into the `.sty` file to `\MakeUpperCase` the "appendix head" but I have no clue where to write that down. Is it a viable solution? Where should I input that (or a more interesting solution if anyone knows one)?

Thanks!

Edit : [here](https://www.overleaf.com/9941614374rqqtgqmxnpsk) is my attempt at a minimal (working) example in an Overleaf playground, so we can see and play around with the .sty file provided. There is also a folder with the whole templates files if needed.

My MWE  is full of bugs (sigh), but we can see that the TOC of appendix and the appendix head share the same formatting (uppercase/lowercase).

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could  post a minimal, yet complete, code demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Note that users here do not like going off site for examples, mainly because those questions will not be relevant to others afterwards as the linked to material might disappear.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments. I modified the original post in an attempt to correct it. To demonstrate the problem I had to rely on the .sty file of 300 lines, so to keep this TeX SX clean I put the example in an Overleaf empty project with open access. @daleif I'll make sure to summarize the answer in an edit in case the material might disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers! They indeed managed to solve the problem, but partially. It eventually interacted with all the rules included in the `.sty` file of the template.

So to summarize the goto answer is :

```
% eventually \appendix here 
\chapter*{THE CHAPTER}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{The chapter}
```

But it may conflict with the `\commands` defined in the `.sty` of a template someone makes use of: like in my case `\Annexe{The chapter}` has a defined style/spacing/etc. (However the answers helped me trace the whole process in the `.sty` so many thanks!)

So you need to either grab in the `.sty` the style to apply and do that to the suggested answer, or  find where and how to resolve that issue by hacking on the `\Annexe` `.sty` directly.

Here is a recap of the process to hopefully help others people diagnose the school template ! :)

First off, the `\newcommand\annexe` defined by the school: here look for your interpretation of `\Annexe` (if it's `\Appendix` search for `\newcommand\appendix`).

In my case it calls `\@annexe` at some point in that command. `\@annexe` is a function that takes as input my "The chapter". Here it is in full :

```
\def\@annexe[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \if@english
                           \addcontentsline{app}{annexe}%
                               {\protect\numberline{Appendix\nobreakspace\thechapter}#1}%
                         \else
                             \addcontentsline{app}{annexe}%
                               {\protect\numberline{Annexe\nobreakspace\thechapter}#1}%
                         \fi  
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{app}{annexe}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{app}{annexe}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makeappendixhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makeappendixhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
```

As we see, it's a mess and it explains why the `\chapter*{}` solution may not have worked as intended. Here we can see the `\addcontentsline{}` command as well. The key to the issue is the `\@makeappendixhead{#2}}` command used, here with the desired `\MakeUppercase{}` command :

```
\def\@makeappendixhead#1{%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \centering
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \if@english
            \normalsize\bfseries APPENDIX\space\thechapter
        \else       
            \normalsize\bfseries ANNEXE\space\thechapter
        \fi
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
        \space\space\space\space
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \normalsize \bfseries {\MakeUppercase{#1}}\par\nobreak 
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

And voilà ! :)

Notice that I don't understand fully how to use the makeuppercase in that context (the double `{{}}` seems fishy to me) but with a few trial and error it eventually worked !

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, you could try with something like this: the first line adds the title (so in your case it should be uppercase) and the second adds it to the TOC (so you type it lowercase).

```
\chapter*{Your Uppercase Title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{your lowercase title}
```

Edit: remember to add `\appendix` before you start appendixes to have them numbered "A.", "B." etc. instead of continuing the numbering from the previous chapters. So the complete code above would be:

```
\appendix
\chapter*{Your Uppercase Title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{your lowercase title}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX.SX! A bit more code would be great, however, if your issue is solely regarding the appendix name being non-capitalised, just declare it as a supressed section in case your document is an article or a chapter in case you chose report format like: `\chapter*{Appendix}`. Subsequently, re-define the name using `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{appendix}` 
Here a schematic exert from my own thesis layout:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
  \chapter*{Abstract}
  \newpage
  \tableofcontents
  \newpage
  \chapter{Chapter 1}
  \newpage
  \chapter*{Appendix}                        %Suppress the capitalised name  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{appendix}   %Manually add the non-capitalised one
  \section{Risk Assessment}
  \section{Proofs}
\end{document}
```

Your appendix will come out like this in your TOC:
[image]